# Can't find a solution of $\sum_{d|n}d^2\mu\left(\frac nd \right)$ using Dirichlet convolution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, mobius-function, dirichlet-convolution

I searched for a solution of the sum $$\sum_{d|n}d^2\mu\left(\frac nd \right)$$ running over the divisors of $n$ and $\mu$ the Möbius function. In the available textbooks it is not dealt with or I overlooked the proof of a helpful result from which one can derive it. Also the generalization would be interesting $$\sum_{d|n}d^k\mu\left (\frac nd\right)$$

Comment: What is a solution of the sum? What does it mean to solve a sum?

Comment: I always hope for a function $f(n)$ which can be written without in any case the sum symbol... (?). E.g. if $k=1$ I at least get $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Having identified this as [Jordan's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_totient_function) it should now be possible to use the material at Wikipedia to supplement the missing content from your textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Dirichlet convolution, $\cdot^2 * \mu $ is a multiplicative function, and:
$$ (\cdot^2*\mu)(p^k) = p^{2k}-p^{2k-2} = p^{2k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)\tag{1} $$
implies:
$$ (\cdot^2*\mu)(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d^2\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = n^2\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right) = n\,\varphi(n)\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right). \tag{2}$$

Comment: I am now puzzled as I originally wanted to calculate with $(\frac d2)^2$ instead of $d^2$. I thought I could take the $\frac 14$ out of the sum. But that seems not to be allowed ? How would I argue for $$\sum_{d|n}(\frac d2)^2\mu(\frac nd)$$ Even worse when I want to calculate with $(\frac dm)^2$ ?!

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann: not allowed?! Why? It is just a constant factor.

Comment: Sorry. Of course. Just confused.

Answer (score 2):

As an  addendum to  the excellent answer  already provided  suppose we
seek to evaluate
$$f_k(n) = \sum_{d|n} d^k\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right).$$

Working with the corresponding Dirichlet series we find that
$$L(s) = \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^s}
\sum_{d|n} d^k\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)
= \left( \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{n^k}{n^s} \right)
\times \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}.$$

This yields
$$L(s) = \frac{\zeta(s-k)}{\zeta(s)}.$$

The Euler product here is
$$L(s) = \prod_p \frac{1-1/p^s}{1-1/p^{s-k}}
=  \prod_p \frac{1-1/p^s}{1-p^k/p^{s}}.$$

Expanding the geometric series we get
$$L(s) =
\prod_p \left(\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{p^{qk}}{p^{qs}}
- \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{p^{qk}}{p^{(q+1)s}} \right).$$

This is
$$L(s) =
\prod_p \left(1 + 
\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{p^{qk}-p^{(q-1)k}}{p^{qs}} \right).$$

This finally implies that $f_k(1) = 1$ and 
$$f_k(p^v) = p^{vk}-p^{(v-1)k}.$$

Therefore we have
$$f_k(n) = n^k\prod_{p|n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^k}\right).$$

This is [Jordan's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_totient_function).